# System.Runtime (.net 4.6) and mscorlib (.net Standard 1.6)

Tags: .net, mscorlib, .net-standard

I have developed an simple .net Standard-Library.

then I referenced this assembly in an .net 4.6 Project which basically works fine.

But when I try to call a method in this .net Standard-library with an bool (or Guid)-parameter I'm getting this error:

> Cannot convert source type 'bool [mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]' to target type
>   'bool [System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]'

These Types are defined in both-assemblies: mscorlib and System.Runtime...how can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

here is an very simple example to Show this error:

**.net Portable Library --> converted to .NET Standard via the property-tab**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void CallMe(Guid guid)
    {
        //so something
    }
}
```

**Project.json**

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {}
  }
}
```

I also had to add this to my csproj-File, outerwise it doesn't work at all:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <NuGetTargetMoniker>.NETStandard,Version=v1.6</NuGetTargetMoniker>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**net 4.6.1 Project** (referenced the .net Standard-library directly via the dll-file (Project-reference is not working)

```
public class Class1
    {
        private void Call()
        {
            var c = new MyClass();
            c.CallMe(Guid.NewGuid());
        }
    }
```

And that is the error-message:
[image]

Comment: Can you give a [mcve], including your project file if it's still as project.json? When you say a ".net 4.6 project" do you mean .NET 4.6, or 4.6.1, or 4.6.2? And is this a .NET Core style project, or a regular csproj? Basically there are lots of details in play here - it would be really helpful to know about them all.

Comment: I've added a simple example to show this error

Comment: You're targeting a netstandard1.6 library from a .NET 4.6.1 project - that's not *supposed* to work - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library. Instead, try targeting netstandard1.4.

Comment: I also suspect that just adding a reference to the DLL directly is a bad idea. I believe that there may be assembly binding redirects needed. Basically, adding a reference from a csproj project to a project.json project is difficult right now - it should all be sorted in the new tooling.

Comment: ok thank you Jon! this fixed my simple example. But in my real Project I have other dependencies which require .NET Standard 1.5 or higher....I think I have to find another solution for that. But anyway - thanks again!

Comment: @TobiasKoller you might post what you have learnt as an answer and accept that.

Comment: @TobiasKoller: For netstandard1.5, you need a .NET 4.6.2 project basically.

Answer (score 2):

@Jon Skeet Thank you for your help.

The problem was an incompatibility between the .net Framework-Version and the .NET Standardversion.

The list can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library